# ¿Cómo detener un bucle y no tomar en cuenta el último valor de la iteración?

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy desarrollando un algoritmo (soy nuevo en esto) el cual me dice que ingrese una lista de números positivos y a su vez vayan sumandose, este es mi código:

```js
let num = 1;
let sum = 0;
let cant = 0;

while (num > 0) {
  num = parseInt(prompt(`Ingrese un numero positivo`));
  console.log(num);

  sum = sum + num;
  cant = cant + 1;
}

promedioNumerosPositivos = sum / cant;
console.log(promedioNumerosPositivos);
```

A medida que le ingreso los números positivos como ya dije se estan sumando y con eso necesito obtener el promedio de los números.

Mi problema esta en que **solo necesito el promedio de los números positivos**, porque cuando le ingreso un numero negativo el while se detiene y al igual se suma a la variable lo cual no quiero, ¿Cómo podria solucionar eso?

El enunciado del problema es el siguiente:

> Diseñe un algoritmo que permita determinar la media de una lista indefinida de números positivos, se debe acabar el programa ingresando un número negativo.

Comment: Intenta usar un `do while` posiblemente sea la solución para tu caso. ;)

Comment: @Israel-ICM no lo tome como un ataque, al contrario volvi a hecharle un vistazo a ver si podria añadirle algo pero la verdad veo todo muy legible pero agregare algo mas para a ver que tal, saludos!

Comment: no te preocupes la pregunta la veo clara, lo que quieres es que al ingresar un negativo se rompa la iteración y que ese número no lo tome en cuenta. ;)

Comment: @Israel-ICM exactamente eso es lo que quiero y al igual he actualizado con una foto para que la gente vea el ejercicio y se le sea mas compresible aun.

Comment: El enunciado es un texto corto, es nada más copiar y pegar... [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).

Answer (score 0):

Fijate si esto te funciona y es lo que necesitas.

**[Math.sign(num)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign)** evalúa si num es positivo o negativo si es 1 o sea positivo hace la suma y si no pues no, igual al darme cuenta de eso vi que puedes hacerlo de distintas formas incluso podrías poner la misma evaluación de arriba **num > 0** pero ahí ya te di otra.

```
if (Math.sign(num) === 1) {
    sum = sum + num;
    cant = cant + 1;
  }
```

Otra forma:

```js
    let sum = 0;
    let cant = 0;
    
    while (true) {
      let num = parseInt(prompt(`Ingrese un numero positivo`));
    
      if (num <= 0) {
        break; // Sale del bucle si el número ingresado es negativo o cero.
      }
    
      console.log(num);
      sum += num;
      cant++;
    }
    
    if (cant > 0) {
      const promedioNumerosPositivos = sum / cant;
      console.log(`El promedio de los números positivos ingresados es: ${promedioNumerosPositivos}`);
    } else {
      console.log("No se ingresaron números positivos.");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No es una solución muy elegante pero basandome en tu código te modifiqué lo siguiente:

```js
let num = 0;
let sum = 0;
let cant = 0;

do {
  sum = sum + num;
  num = parseInt(prompt(`Ingrese un numero positivo`));
} while (num > 0 && ++cant)

promedioNumerosPositivos = sum / cant;
console.log(promedioNumerosPositivos);
```

Primeramente todos los valores son asignados a cero, como te habia mencionado en los comentarios posiblemente era mejor usar un `do while` para tu caso, ya que de esta forma la primera iteración ingresará sin importarle el cero, en el caso de la petición del número por `prompt` iria despues del cálculo de suma para que en la primera iteración solo sume un `0` y no `1` como antes lo hacia. En este caso como la comparación while está al final cada vez que ingreses un número se compara inmediatamente y de esta manera se romperá la iteración, para incrementar la cantidad solo uso un `++cant` para que se vaya sumando en cada iteración.

Answer (score 0):

Ya te han dado la respuesta a tu problema de fondo. Pero para responder la pregunta que haces en el titulo:

> ¿Cómo detener un bucle?

Esto con un [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) el cual detiene cualquier loop, ya sea for o while. Además detiene los case

```js
let num = 1;
let sum = 0;
let cant = 0;

while (num > 0) {
  num = parseInt(prompt(`Ingrese un numero positivo`));
  
  if(num<0){
    break;
  }
  
  
  console.log(num);

  sum = sum + num;
  cant = cant + 1;
}

promedioNumerosPositivos = sum / cant;
console.log(promedioNumerosPositivos);
```

---

Otra forma de detener una iteración es con un return, solo cuando el código está dentro de una función

<sub>Nota: El código a continuación no es buen código, está implementado de esa forma solo para mantener la coherencia con el código original</sub>

```js
let num = 1;
let sum = 0;
let cant = 0;

function Promediar(){
  while (num > 0) {
    num = parseInt(prompt(`Ingrese un numero positivo`));

    if(num<0){
      return;
    }

    console.log(num);
    sum = sum + num;
    cant = cant + 1;
  }
}

Promediar();
promedioNumerosPositivos = sum / cant;
console.log(promedioNumerosPositivos);
```

---

Existe otra palabra clave que es `continue` que cuando está en una iteración, pasa al siguiente loop saltado lo que se encuentra por debajo de esa palabra. En tu caso particular, al tener un `while` que cuenta con una condición provocaría un efecto similar al `brake`

```js
let num = 1;
let sum = 0;
let cant = 0;

while (num > 0) {
  num = parseInt(prompt(`Ingrese un numero positivo`));
  
  if(num<0){
    continue;
  }
  
  
  console.log(num);

  sum = sum + num;
  cant = cant + 1;
}

promedioNumerosPositivos = sum / cant;
console.log(promedioNumerosPositivos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solución usando una expresión equivalente al operador **Walrus** de Python:

```js
const arr = []
while ((num = parseInt(prompt(`>>`))) > 0) arr.push(num);
const avg = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / arr.length;
console.log(avg);
```